# Turn off the new window animation on chrome for macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, animation

I searched around on google and did find one answer but it seemed as that only worked for Ubuntu. I'm trying to disable the "maximize" effect of chrome when opening a new window. Chrome is the only app that does this and no other app on my mac has a "maximize" animation for a new window and it's bothering me a ton. Is there any way to disable this animation permanently on macOS? It's super annoying.

I tried adding the `--wm-window-animations-disabled` to an exec file and runnning chrome from there but it doesnt work

Comment: Cant help towards an answer, but just updated it to have a look…. can't say it would bother me, tbh. It's there, but it's so fast as to hardly notice.

Comment: idk it heavily bothers me cause i like having everything the same. Chrome only app that opens like that and its annoying cause no other app does that

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448552/turn-off-chrome-new-window-animation

Comment: yea i didn't know which SE site to use and i didn't know not to do that sorry

Comment: No worries - it's on-topic at either, so take your pick & delete the other.

Answer (score 0):

This effect bugs me too and I finally found the fix:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false
```

Found at: https://www.chriswrites.com/boost-your-macs-performance-by-disabling-unnecessary-animations/

Comment: thank you so much !